# IOS - UISegmented in UITableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

I insert a segmented in uitableview [like this url image](http://mocku.ps/qb6o64). If you see the url image, now i'm working ok everything data in uitable,

and...

When i scroll down table i wanna part 1: Image(in url) will scroll scroll to part 2: segmented will stop and if you still scroll uitable part 3: the data will be scroll (keep segmented on the top).

Have you any idea it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just test it, it is working!

1. Set your UITableView pain
2. UITableView has two section and each section has only one row.
3. When edit your section header, make sure only second section has header - second header will be your part2.
4. first section first row is your part1.
5. second section first row is your part3.

That's it : )

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

        cell.textLabel.text = @"test";

        return cell;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    @try {
        UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 30)];
        switch (section) {
            case 0:
            {
                //nothing
            }
                break;
            case 1:
            {
                UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 30)];
                lbl.text = @"second";
                lbl.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                [containerView addSubview:lbl];
            }
                break;
        }
        return containerView;
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
    }
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 30;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 1000.0;
}
```

Comment: Thank @brian for quickly answer, i will try it!